# Scala Playframework connection with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, scala, docker, playframework

I try to connect my Play Backend with my Postgresql Database, but get:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.]]
```

Database is running on Port 5432 (checked it)

I´m using sbt and Play 2.8.2
Already tried 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, doesn't matter (would be strange if, but you never know) 
Also im using Docker-Compose to create the database.

Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
....

val connection= DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/smartmarkt", "postgres", "postgres") 

            println("Connected to PostgreSQL database!");
            var statement = connection.createStatement();
            var resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Article");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                println(resultSet, resultSet.getString("price"));
            }
```

Dockerfile

```
services:
  web:
    build: frontend/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - api

  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=smartmarkt  
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    volumes:
     - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
     #- ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data # persist data even if container shuts downvolumes:

  api:
    build: backend/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - database
    depends_on: 
      - database
```

I add jdbc in my build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += jdbc
```

Also i have the *postgresql-42.2.13.jar* in my */lib* dic, but to be honest, i dont actually know if its getting used.

Comment: You can access the database from your application using `postgres://database:5432`
Check this https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: @ShankarShastri dosnt work for me, now i get " No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://database:5432" (also without the jdbc: leading) Not sure if this is a step backward or forward

Comment: `jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/smartmarkt` This should work @Proxy. It's explained from docker documentation itself with postgres as example.

Comment: I tried `jdbc:postgresql://database:5432` WITHOUT */smartmark*. I though `database:5432` would link me directly to my configured database (they didnt use the  environment tag in the documentation) . Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: I've added a answer, please mark the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/smartmarkt
```

The above connection string will work as within docker network containers can be accessed by their hostnames.